# SQL Query for select data from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have multiple tables with same metadata (column names are same). I want to select Latest Records from these table, ordered by `CreationDate` (such column exist in all tables).
[image: Something like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT newTable.MyData, newTable.CreationDate FROM
(SELECT MyData, CreationDate FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT MyData, CreationDate FROM Table2) AS newTable
ORDER BY newTable.CreationDate DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure of the correct syntax in MSSQL, but you should be able to:

```
SELECT ... FROM table1 UNION table2
```

(where table1 and table2 have identical columns)

Hope this helps...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: It worked: `SELECT top(3) OwnerID,NewsTitle,NewsCreationDate FROM MoviesNews UNION 
SELECT top(3) OwnerID,NewsTitle,NewsCreationDate FROM  TheaterNews
ORDER BY 3 DESC`

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use alias for the tables and select all the columns of both the tables and give the columns different names as per the table names. I think this can help you out.

Thanks,
Dipa

Comment: The query can be like SELECT t1.[x] As 'X1',t2.[x] as 'X2' FROM [table1] as t1 INNER JOIN [table2] as t2 On t1.[y] = t2.[y]